# Error trying to remove box element from array based on a true/false if statement

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I have a user-defined function that takes an array with box elements and extends those boxes for each candle to the right until the candles touch the box.  When the candle touches the box, I want the option to delete the box from the array.  I try this using an 'if' statement: `if i_mz_delete_toggle`, which is a user input boolean (i.e., a checkbox).  If this returns true, then I want to remove that box from the array, which is done with `array.remove(_boxes, i)`.
I get an error when trying to compile: "Return type of one of the 'if' or 'switch' blocks is not compatible with return type of other block(s) (series box; void)"
The problem is with the `if i_mz_delete_toggle` `array.remove(_boxes, i)` part of the code, as the rest of the user-defined function works just fine without these.

```
_extendDZbox(_boxes, _low) =>
    if array.size(_boxes) > 0
        for i = array.size(_boxes) - 1 to 0 by 1
            _box = array.get(_boxes, i)
            _boxLow = box.get_bottom(_box)
            _boxHigh = box.get_top(_box)
            _boxRight = box.get_right(_box)
            if low >= _boxHigh and bar_index == _boxRight
                box.set_right(_box, bar_index + 1)
            else
                if low < _boxHigh and bar_index == _boxRight
                    if i_mz_delete_toggle
                        array.remove(_boxes, i)
                    else
                        if i_mz_recolor_toggle
                            box.set_right(_box, bar_index)
                            box.set_bgcolor(_box, i_mz_color)
                            box.set_border_color(_box, i_mz_color)
                            box.set_text_color(_box, i_mz_label_color)
                        else
                            box.set_right(_box, bar_index)
```

I tried removing everything else, including the `if i_mz_delete_toggle` statement, such that the code reads:

```
_extendDZbox(_boxes, _low) =>
    if array.size(_boxes) > 0
        for i = array.size(_boxes) - 1 to 0 by 1
            _box = array.get(_boxes, i)
            _boxLow = box.get_bottom(_box)
            _boxHigh = box.get_top(_box)
            _boxRight = box.get_right(_box)
            if low >= _boxHigh and bar_index == _boxRight
                box.set_right(_box, bar_index + 1)
            else
                if low < _boxHigh and bar_index == _boxRight
                    array.remove(_boxes, i)
```

The idea was to isolate the array.remove function to see if it would work on its own, but I ended up getting the same error from this.  I'm not sure where the incompatible return type is coming from.

Answer (score 0):

After some additional testing, I found one solution that works.  It may not be the only solution, and I still don't fully understand why the original code gave the error.  The solution I found was to use the box.delete function with the array.get function for the current array element.  The line `array.remove(_boxes, i)` has been replaced with `box.delete(array.get(_boxes, i))`.  Therefore the new code is:

```
_extendDZbox(_boxes, _low) =>
if array.size(_boxes) > 0
    for i = array.size(_boxes) - 1 to 0 by 1
        _box = array.get(_boxes, i)
        _boxLow = box.get_bottom(_box)
        _boxHigh = box.get_top(_box)
        _boxRight = box.get_right(_box)
        _boxRange = _boxHigh - _boxLow
        mt = _boxHigh - math.round_to_mintick(_boxRange * mit_threshold)
        if low >= mt and bar_index == _boxRight
            box.set_right(_box, bar_index + 1)
        else
            if low < mt and bar_index == _boxRight
                if i_mz_delete_toggle
                    box.delete(array.get(_boxes, i))
                else
                    if i_mz_recolor_toggle
                        box.set_right(_box, bar_index)
                        box.set_bgcolor(_box, i_mz_color)
                        box.set_border_color(_box, i_mz_color)
                        box.set_text_color(_box, i_mz_label_color)
                    else
                        box.set_right(_box, bar_index)
```